# Install4j - Register a hidden variable to a response var file

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to make a hidden variable appear in a response var file.

We have a database password variable which should be hidden (not appear in the logs)

```
context.registerHiddenVariable("db.password");
```

However, I want my users to know that they can input that variable in an unattended installation.

```
context.setVariable("db.password","******");
context.registerResponseFileVariable("db.password");
```

The response var file doesn't contain the variable.
I couldn't find anyway to un-hide the variable or to work around this.

Comment: Just figured out that it has to do with the value of the variable.

Apparently, When I've set the variable to empty string, it didn't appear in the response file. When I set it to ***** it did.

Answer (score 1):

You could try manually updating the file with a "Run script" action placed after your "Create a response file" action (if you are using that action):

```
String varFilePath = (String) context.getVariable("sys.installationDir") + "\\.install4j\\response.varfile";
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(varFilePath, true));
bufferedWriter.newLine();
bufferedWriter.append("db.password=******");
bufferedWriter.close();

return true;
```